# Why does adding a "border" property to this document make everything look fine?

Tags: html, css

First, here is my markup, it's basically a container with a repeated background picture, and then another div container inside it that contains a "p" element inside it as well.

```
<div class="background">
 <div class="transbox">
   <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
    This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS.

```
div.background {width:500px; height:250px; background: url(logo.jpg) repeat; border:1px solid black;}
div.transbox {margin:40px 50px; border:1px solid black; width:400px; height:180px; background-color:white; opacity:0.6; filter: alpha(opacity=60);}
div.transbox p {margin: 30px 40px; font-weight:bold; color:black;}
```

Now here's where I get confused, if I don't put a "border" property in the "background" div, the layout gets messed up, the margin of the "transbox" div also affects the "background" div along with it, therefore making the "transbox" div not perfectly centered and ultimately ruining the layout.

But when I add the "border" property, everything seems to fall into place, the layout becomes perfect and I don't get it.

Am I missing something here? is there some kind of rule that is subtly affecting the layout?

Comment: I've just [made a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq8720uo/) with your code and I wouldn't say it looks all that fine... Are you talking about horizontal or vertical centering?

Comment: or try adding `display: inline-block;` to `div.transbox` instead of border - http://jsfiddle.net/9ezx9b73/

Comment: @ialarmedalien Vertical centering please.

Comment: You're suffering the [curse of the collapsing margins](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/). Mary Melody has posted a fix, but you can read about other options in the article I've linked to.

Comment: I see, thank you, but this is very unsettling, because I couldn't believe that such a simple "border" property could fix an entire document, that's CSS for us, full of surprises.

Comment: @JohnsyOmniscient I would say, "that's CSS for us, full of surprises." More like, "that's those that don't understand the fundamentals of CSS, full of surprises." Collapsing margins are a GOOD thing.